# Incorrectly notified of "Mortarboard" badge

Tags: bug, badges

I just saw a new badge notification:

> You've earned the "Mortarboard" badge (Earn at least 200 reputation
>   (the daily maximum) in a single day).

[image: screenshot]

But I am nowhere near 200 rep this day (only +30 rep, no bounties or whatever at least I am not aware of) not even in combination with other SE sites.

After some digging I found:

> Awarded Nov 19 '18 at 22:50

[image: screenshot]

which was more or less exactly year ago so it looks like its **just a glitch in notification system.**

Comment: Maybe worth reporting to SE? After all, RC.SE hasn't much say in that case.

Comment: @Raffzahn hmm can you migrate this in there ?

Comment: @Raffzahn looks I am not the only one see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338551/236640

Comment: Oh, yes. Seams like you got some additional Rep due the recalculation event. Cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Raffzahn said, this is a retroactive awarding of the badge due to the change that made upvotes on questions worth +10 reputation. If you take a look at the 2018-11-19 entry on [your reputation log](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/reputation), you'll see that it's correct.